# Refering to self instance from within a model class

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model class, and I want to pass the instance to a method from within this class model:

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField()
    ...several fields...
    user= models.CharField(max_length=50, db_column='user', editable=False) # Field name made lowercase.
    myFile = models.FileField(max_length=256, blank=True, upload_to=create_file_name(instance, myString))
```

If I want to define a method `create_file_name` with one of the params the model instance itself, I don't know how to refer to it.
I know that if I just call `upload_to=create_file_name` with no params, the method takes automatically instance and filename, but I want to pass the instance and a specific string (not the filename).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
upload_to = lambda instance, filename : create_file(instance, 'whatever')
```

Comment: This is just what I was looking for. I will explore what is this "lambda" thing